# NGINX as Reverse Proxy + Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, firewall

I have IPFIRE as my Firewall. It's works great but i have a little problem with this scenario.. In my network, IPFIRE have 3 nics (GREEN, RED AND ORANGE) and i have 2 physical servers in the ORANGE ZONE (SVR_1 ip 10.10.1.207 and SVR_2 ip 10.10.1.201). Both servers have LAMP infrastructure (CentOS as default OS). SVR_1 have lets encrypt ssl cert installed. SVR_2 dont have lets encrypt installed because we need to buy the domain (now we are using NOIP)
The problem begins when i need NGINX forward the 443 traffic to apache to handle with the request and show the website.My configuration with port 80 works great!.
There is some solution with my problem? i know that nginx can use "STREAM" mod, but ipfire doesnt have this mod available

Thanks all!

Comment: Where is nginx?

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton Nginx is installed in the ipfire. It's an addon!